# Django Tastypie YUI Model-relate foreignKey id instead of resource_uri

Tags: javascript, django, yui, tastypie

It seems that Django TastyPie JSON produces foreign keys as a value that matches the full resource_uri of the related model. YUI3s model-relate expects JSON foreign keys to be the Id of the related field. Is there a setting in YUI model-relate or in TastyPie resource definitions to get these two frameworks talking easily?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the model definitions. Specifically, I had the "root" attribute in the wrong place. Once I fixed that, model-relate and tastypie started behaving as expected.

```
Y.WorkerProfileModel = Y.Base.create(
        'workerProfileModel', Y.Model, [Y.ModelRelate, Y.ModelSync.REST], 
            { root: '/api/v1/workerprofile/'},
            { ATTRS: {
                user: {},
                shortCode: {}
            }
        }
    );

    Y.RequestEventModel = Y.Base.create(
        'requestEventModel', Y.Model, [Y.ModelRelate, Y.ModelSync.REST], 
            { root: '/api/v1/requestevent/' },
            { ATTRS: {
                requestType: {},
                requestStatus: {}
            },
            RELATIONSHIPS: {
                workerProfile: {
                    type: 'toOne',
                    key: 'id',
                    relatedModel: 'WorkerProfileModel',
                    relatedKey: 'workerProfileId'
                }
            }
        }
    );
```